# Redirect to Authentication Provider Page instead of salesforce login page

Tags: single-sign-on, oauth, auth-provider, open-id-connect

I have created an open id connection between external authentication provider and salesforce. Now the requirement is when my domail url is entered in browser, it has to redirect to authentication provider page and from there the user has to log in to salesforce by providing his credentials. Instead it is staying in login.salesforce.com page. Can anyone help me achieving this functionality.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Go to Setup > (Company Settings | Domain Management) > My Domain, edit the Authentication Configuration section, and uncheck all settings except for the provider you want to use. Salesforce will then automatically redirect all login requests from your domain to the specified provider. If more than one option is available, users can choose from any of the checked providers.

Comment: Thanks sfdcfox. Now I can able to login from external auth provider.
The other requirement is when I tried to login with the user who is in salesforce and auth provider, it is creating new user when ever I login into salesforce. I have my registration controller set as to update user if any user is found with specific profile but it is creating new user when ever the user logs in the first time. Can you please help me with this requirement?